# Secure communication between processes using gRPC

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, grpc, grpc-python

I have a gRPC service communicating with the clients on the same machine. I'd like to restrict access to the service only for the user, who started the service. For example, only 'patrik' can access service running as user 'patrik'.

Q: If I have SSH key pair (id_rsa, id_rsa.pub), is it possible to use them for authentication?

Q: If I already have CA certificate, can I do smth like:
`openssl req -new -x509 -in myCA.crt -key id_rsa -out cacert.pem`

And use the triplet as an input to the gRPC? (Notice the same content of the files for Client and Server):

```
    # Server auth
    server_credentials = grpc.ssl_server_credentials(
            [(id_rsa, id_rsa.pub)],
            root_certificates=cacert.pem,
            require_client_auth=True
        )
    server.add_secure_port("[::]:50051", server_credentials)

    # Client
    credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(cacert.pem, id_rsa, id_rsa.pub)
    channel = aio.secure_channel('127.0.0.1:50051', credentials)
```

I have this setup running, however, for every request I am getting *No match found for server name: 127.0.0.1.*

Comment: I've not tried converting SSH key pairs to TLS and it seems not straightforward. Would it not be simpler to generate your own certificates (client+server) and configure your sevice to mTLS with these?

Comment: Instead of using myCA.crt, I've created self-signed crt: `openssl req -new -x509 -key id_rsa -out cacert.pem`. id_rsa should be in the correct format already. With this setup it's working.